# Exchange ActiveSync with multiple email addresses

Tags: exchange-2007, activesync, windows-mobile

I have Exchange 2007 SP2, and I have successfully connected my Windows Mobile phone via Exchange ActiveSync and can send and receive emails.

I have two addresses within my Exchange mailbox, *martin@domain1.co.uk* and *martin@domain2.co.uk*, with the second being set as the reply address.

When I view my email addresses on my device, I see both of these email addresses, however when I send new messages it always selects the first email address as the reply address and not the second.

It is probably worth pointing out that, like in the example provided above, the email addresses are shown alphabetically and the address being selected is the first alphabetically (just in case that matters).

I would like to set the device to always select the reply address specified in the mailbox, or at least be able to ensure that the address I want is selected if I have to select it manually on the device, but cannot find any way to make this happen.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

If you try sending from your MS Outlook client on the desktop- does the same happen as from the device?

If yes you have to check the server side settings as per

http://www.petri.co.il/change_primary_email_address_in_exchange_2007.htm

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvrtransport/thread/3928de1d-bb57-
4bf5-b9fb-3d57c88cbdc3

Comment: Thanks, but everything works fine from Outlook.

Comment: This should be the answer.  Whatever your primary address is in Exchange should be what your outgoing address is on an active sync device.  What version of Windows Mobile?